# Apache stops the script

Tags: php, apache

I have a problem with a PHP script allows download files outside of the site, directly on the pc of the user.

It works perfectly on an OVH VPS with Apache and PHP stanadard configuration standard. In other VPS to another provider with the same configuration, the same script stops downloading after 50 seconds.

And the browser (Chrome) reports unknown error of the network.

I tried to set `set_time_limit(0)` in the script, but it does't work, I changed the timeout in the `php.ini`, but still does not work, ask for help to understand what can depend this.

Comment: Well, certainly no one can help if you don't explain how your script works. Post your code, reduced to the relevant bits and explain how it should work.

Comment: What does "download files outside of the site, directly on the pc of the user" mean? How did you verify the config was the same? What happens when you trace the exchange with a packet capture?

Answer (score 1):

You've changed parameter that manages time of *execution* of script, but you need to change parameter that responsible for time needed for parsing request data. It's `max_input_time` - so you can change it in php.ini or via function [ini_set()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried to set max_input_time to 120 or higher, and even to 0, but the problem remains the same, on the other vps max_input_time is set to 60 and everything works normally
This Is my php:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
function get_size($url) {
$my_ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($my_ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($my_ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($my_ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($my_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($my_ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 35);
$r = curl_exec($my_ch);
foreach(explode("\n", $r) as $header) {
    if(strpos($header, 'Content-Length:') === 0) {
        return trim(substr($header,16));
    }
}
return '';
}

$url=base64_decode(filter_var($_GET['url']));
$name =($_GET['title']);
$size=get_size($url);
//echo $url."<br>".$size;

// Fetch and serve
if ($url)
{
$size=get_size($url);
// Generate the server headers
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE)
{
header('Content-Type: application/octet-string');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Length: '.$size);
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Pragma: public');
}
else
{
header('Content-Type: application/octet-string');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Length: '.$size);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
}

readfile($url);
exit;
}

//Not found;
exit('File not found');
?>
```